# MySQL Error Message on first load

Tags: php, mysql

I just uploaded my site that is linked with a MySQL database (Its my first time)

When I open the page that pulls info from the database it always comes up with this error (it goes away when I refresh)

Warning: mysql_pconnect() [function.mysql-pconnect]: MySQL server has gone away in D:\Hosting\2941136\html\test_sites\solera2013\Connections\SoleraMenuSystem.php on line 9

Can anyone tell me why this error pops up the first time the page loads and goes away after refresh

Thanks
Dan

Here is the site: http://graves-incorporated.com/test_sites/solera2013/menu_dinner.php

Comment: Are there InnoDB tables? I have had this issue before and it is likely  one or more tables are corrupt.

Comment: Yes, I believe they are, if I change them to isam would that help?

Comment: My advice to you... if you are just starting out with PHP/MySQL, don't use persistent connections (pconnect) unless you know what you are doing with these, it can lead to lots of problems.  Also you shouldn't use `mysql_*` functions at all,as they are deprecated. Instead learn `mysqli` or `PDO`

Comment: I didn't realize I was using pconnect or know what that means.  I just taught myself MySQL, are you telling me I wasted all my time? haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read MySQL reference for this error message:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/gone-away.html

Answer (score 0):

You should increase `mysql.connect_timeout option`

```
 ini_set('mysql.connect_timeout', 500);
 ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 500);
```

you can also ping your connection that it is alive or lost

```
if(!mysql_ping($connection)){
// reconnect
}
```